# symfony4 и bootstrap3

Tags: symfony4

Подскажите, можно ли совместить symfony4 и bootstrap3, не используя webpack, как это было в symfony3?

Comment: просто подключите бутстрап файлы в ваш базовый шаблон и всё

Comment: а различного рода less, css файлы хранить в любой мною созданной папке?

Comment: да, либо воспользоваться encore

Comment: так это webpack

Comment: да, если не  хотите webpack тогда просто положите файлы в public и подключайте их оттуда